# Figuring out how to loop in a way that (sum of x numbers = y)

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm having a bit of difficulty with this algorithmic question. Find all possible outcomes for a given sum (y) assuming you must use (x) amount of numbers.

So assuming my x = 3 and my sum is 60. I have to figure out all possible scenarios. For example 
    `1,1,58`, `1,2,57` etc... There's a bit more complexity to it, but not important here.

I can figure out x=2, x=3, but it's being done manually and I need to figure out how to do it dynamically.

```
    for ($first=$start; $first <= $highest_number; $first++) { //start = 1, highest_number = y / x which is 20 in this case.
        for ($inc=$start; $inc <= $end; $inc++) { //end = 40

            if ($x>= 3) { //assuming x = 3

                for ($n=$highest_number; $n <= $end ; $n++) { 
                    if ( $first + $inc + $n == $target ) {
                        $result['result'][] = $first .",". $inc .",". $n;
                    }
                }

            } else  { // assuming x = 2
                if ($first + $inc == $target) {
                    $result['result'][] = $first .",". $inc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where I'm stuck. So obviously I'm using a conditional for x=2, x=3 right now. What's the best way to do it dynamically? I'm thinking recursive function, I don't have anything working, but this is how I imagine it would look:

```
    //recursion - does not work, not sure how to make it work
    $z = 1;
    function test($x, $first, $inc){
        while ($z<= $x) {

            //this is where I'm stuck. How do i form my loop so that it works dynamically. 
            for ($n=$start; $n <= $end ; $n++) { 

            }

        }
    }
```

Can anyone give tips on how to form my recursive function so that it accounts for any number of x in the equation?

Comment: Recursion seems like the way to go. Select the first number in the result, subtract it from `y`, then recurse with `y = y-first` and `x=x-1`. Stop when `y < x`. Then repeat with a different first number.

Comment: x nested loops - generate an array of arrays where subarrays all have length x

Comment: looks like y^x loop iterations (assuming e.g. 1,59 not the same as 59,1), unless I misunderstand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

This is nHr combination where n=y, r=x-y.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

class nHr
{
public:
    nHr(int n, int r) {
        this->n = n;
        this->r = r;
        ar = new int[r];
    }
    int* ar;
    int n, r;
    bool next() {
        ar[r-1]++;
        int i = r-1;
        while(ar[i] == n+1) {
            if(--i == -1) return false;
            ar[i]++;
        }
        while(i < r-1) ar[i+1] = ar[i++];
        return true;
    }
    int operator[](int n) {return ar[n];}
};

int main(int c, char** v)
{
    if(c < 3) return 0;
    int x = atoi(v[1]);
    int y = atoi(v[2]);
    nHr nhr(y, x-y);
    map<int, int> m;
    while(nhr.next()) {
        for(int i=1; i<=y; i++) m[i]++;
        for(int i=0; i<x-y; i++) m[nhr[i]]++;
        for(auto& a : m) cout << a.second << ',';
        cout << endl;
        m.clear();
    }
}
```

[image]